# HK2 IterableProvider named method not finding Implementation

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jersey, jersey-2.0, hk2

I have a problem trying to inject a contract with two services bound to it.

I'm using Jersey, and extending `ResourceConfig` to configure my app, where I'm binding two different implementations (classes `FooImpl1` and `FooImpl2`) to a same contract (interface `Foo`), ranking them differently. Each of these implementations is annotated with `@Named` and its name.

In one of my controllers I want to have access to both implementations, so I inject an `IterableProvider<Foo> fooProvider`.

If I do not specify anything, the implementation with the highest rank is injected always, which is what I want.

The problem appears when I want a concrete implementation, one of them. When I call `fooProvider.named( nameOfTheClass ).get()`, is returning me null, but if I iterate over the fooProvider, I can have access to both implementations, so they are injected.

Anybody has an idea of what could I be missing?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Instead of `named( nameOfTheClass )`, try `named( namedAnnotationValue )`, as stated in the [javadoc](https://hk2.java.net/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/api/IterableProvider.html#named%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: namedAnnotationValue is the same String as nameOfTheClass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah so I'm not sure why it doesn't work with the `@Named` annotation value, as that's what's stated int the [javadoc](https://hk2.java.net/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/api/IterableProvider.html#named%28java.lang.String%29), but without the need for any annotations, we can configure the name when we do our bindings. We can do so with the [`named`](https://hk2.java.net/hk2-api/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/utilities/binding/ServiceBindingBuilder.html#named%28java.lang.String%29) method.

```
register(new AbstractBinder(){
    @Override
    public void configure() {
        bind(Foo1Impl.class).named("foo1").to(Foo.class);
        bind(Foo2Impl.class).named("foo2").to(Foo.class);
    }
});
```

---

#### UPDATE

So the above solution has been tested. If you are having problems still, post a complete runnable example that demonstrates it not working, like below (which is working)

Interface and Implementations

```
public interface Greeter {
    String getGreeting(String name);
}

public class EnglishGreeter implements Greeter {
    @Override
    public String getGreeting(String name) {
        return "Hello " + name + "!";
    }
}

public class SpanishGreeter implements Greeter {
    @Override
    public String getGreeting(String name) {
        return "Hola " + name + "!";
    }
}
```

Resource

```
@Path("greeting")
public class GreetingResource {
    
    @Inject
    private IterableProvider<Greeter> greeters;
    
    @GET
    public Response getResponse(@QueryParam("lang") String lang,
                                @QueryParam("name") String name) throws Exception {
        
        Greeter greeter = greeters.named(lang).get();
        String message = greeter.getGreeting(name);
        return Response.ok(message).build();
    }
}
```

Binding. I did it in a `Feature`, but in a `ResourceConfig`, it's all the same.

```
@Provider
public class GreetingFeature implements Feature {
    @Override
    public boolean configure(FeatureContext context) {
        context.register(new AbstractBinder(){
            @Override
            public void configure() {
                bind(EnglishGreeter.class).named("english")
                        .to(Greeter.class).in(Singleton.class);
                bind(SpanishGreeter.class).named("spanish")
                        .to(Greeter.class).in(Singleton.class);
            }
        });
        return true;
    }  
}
```

Result

[image]

Comment: Actually, is still not working even specifying the named annotation when binding.

Comment: I actually tested this before posting

Comment: See UPDATE with test results