# Is there a way to inject an instance into a Collection using HK2?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, hk2

Let's say we have the following code:

```
@Inject
private Collection<SomeKind> myCollection;
```

What I want is that the dependencies after they were solved (I mean, all the classes that are of SomeKind type), could also being added to the collection. I know I can inject the ServiceLocator, and programmatically search for the instances on the registry, and then add them to the collection by myself, I just was wondering if there is a common mechanism for this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is an [`IterableProvider<SomeKind>`](https://hk2.java.net/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/api/IterableProvider.html). See the [Documentation](https://hk2.java.net/2.4.0-b07/introduction.html#IterableProvider).

It's an [Iterable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html?is-external=true), so you can use it in a for each loop

```
for (SomeKind someKind: someKinds) {
    ...
}
```

You could look them up by name

```
@Inject
IterableProvider<SomeKind> someKinds;
...
SomeKind someKind = someKinds.named("someName").get();
```

Here's a [complete example using Jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29302411/2587435)