# Injecting multiple child classes into service with Jersey and HK2

Tags: dependency-injection, jersey, hk2

I have an abstract class `AbstractTimerTask` that extends `TimerTask` and I have a Jersey service that is going to manage these timer tasks.  I will have more than one implementation of the abstract class, and I would like them all injected into the service.  If possible, I would like to be able to inject them into a list of type `List<AbstractTimerTask>`.  It is possible that one or more of the child classes will not be available, depending on which jar files I deploy to the server.  I would like only the child classes that are available to be injected.  For this reason, I can't just list the classes in the service class as individual dependencies and build the list myself.

Is it possible to inject multiple classes with the same parent type into a list of that parent type?

Comment: In particular hk2 was designed to work very well in situations where the child classes are added or removed at runtime.  It allows for a very dynamic set of runtime services that can change during the lifetime of the JVM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can inject [`IterableProvder<AbstractTimerTask>`](https://hk2.java.net/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/api/IterableProvider.html), as seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29302411/2587435)