# How can I bind multiple instances to one interface in HK2 and Jersey?

Tags: kotlin, jersey, hk2

I am trying to use DI to inject WebTarget into my class in Jersey

I have this binding in my binder:

```
val WTInstance1 : WebTarget = /* code creating the webTarget instance */
val WTInstance2 : WebTarget = /* code creating the webTarget instance */

bind(WTInstance1).to(WebTarget::class.java).named("target1")
bind(WTInstance2).to(WebTarget::class.java).named("target2")
```

I have this class:

```
class SomeService() {
    @Inject
    @Named("target2")
    lateinit var target : WebTarget
}
```

I would expect WTInstance2 to be injected, but I get WTInstance1 (actually I always get the first binded instance)

Questions:
Do I understand using @Named annotation concept correctly?
If so, any idea why it does not work?

Comment: Look at your two `bind()` calls.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha I am sorry, they were same in the question (but not i my app) I edited it.

Comment: Try to do `bind(WTInstance2).named("target2").to(WebTarget::class.java)`. You can see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29302411/2587435), it works fine.

Comment: I also tried to call named(), before to() as you are suggesting, but without luck. I can see a difference between this and your example. In my case I have two instances of the same class in your example there are two implementations of one interface. I am not sure if that matter.

Comment: If this is using hk2 (not 100% sure it is) then you can try to use ServiceLocatorUtilities.dumpAllDescriptors to see what service descriptions are in the locator.  That'll tell you if your bind worked properly